# ValidationMessage throwing observable is not validatable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a viewmodel and it has an observable, and there are some validations I applied on it.

Now when I use the custom `validationMessage` binding, to display error, I get the following error in ko validation library:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TEXTBOX_Template">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: question().s_answer" />
    <span class="validationMessage" 
          data-bind="validationMessage: question().s_answer"></span>
</script>
```

[image: KO validationMessage error]

I am using latest version of both ko and ko-validation.

My setup is as following:

```
ko.validation.init({ decorateInputElement: false, 
                     messageTemplate: 'error_Template' });
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("selectedOptions");
```

Error template (but not required in this example as I want to use `validationMessage`):

```
<script type="text/html" id="error_Template">
    <!-- ko if: (field.isModified() && !field.isValid()) -->
    <span class="validationMessage" data-bind="text: field.error"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

If this works with observable, then it should work with observableArray because I have a list of radio buttons using ko foreach and when there is validation, the error is displayed after each of the input radio buttons.

Any suggestions would help !

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the jsFiddle you give. It does not seem to have anything in common with your question (no template, no input tag...). We need more info here, like your viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for clearing up bits. Sorry about the jsFiddle, it was just for playing around. Validation works fine in jsFiddle but not in my code. I have removed it now. So the problem is occurring in both input and select controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some issue with the validationMessage binding, so we need to explicitly extend the observable to be validatable.

Add the below line in the knockout.validation.js file under validationMessage binding handler:

```
obsv.extend({ validatable: true });
```

[image]

Hopefully this will be fixed in next version, added an issue in ko.validation. Or atleast this worked for me, let me know if I am wrong? Or is there a better way?